Why the order of elements doesn't matter in a class?
In the example, i have declared and initialised all the data members after the getInfo() function. I expected it to give an error because the members are not yet declared but it is working perfectly. I am confused how it is working because in the main function you have to declare a variable before using it.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class teacher
{
    public:
    void getInfo() {
        cout << name << endl;
        cout << dept << endl;
        cout << subject << endl;
        cout << salary << endl;
    }

    teacher(string n, string de, string sub, int sal) {
        name = n;
        dept = de;
        subject = sub;
        salary = sal;
    }

    string name;
    string dept;
    string subject;
    int salary;
};

int main()
{
    teacher t1("Muneeb", "CS", "Civics", 2000);
    t1.getInfo();
    return 0;
}


You are "using" the variables in getInfo when you call that function and you initialize the variables when you call the constructor. The members are declared in the class before that happens.

@GuyIncognito I think the OP is asking why e.g. the name member can be refered to in getInfo before it is defined (looking at the order in the source code), but the same cannot be done for a local variable. But this is simply how the language works.

The rules for names in classes are different from the rules for names in functions. In a class the compiler will lookahead to see what names are defined.

Function bodies are processed separately after the rest of the class.

C has its rules for declaration and name reference.  C inherited those rules.  For the parts of the language that C++ extended from C, C++ has its own rules for declaration and name reference for the parts of the language that were C++.  In this case, the C++ context of the code allows for the declaration to follow after the use.

Side note: Your code has several flaws so I rewrote it (enhanced and optimized), here. You may learn quite a bit from it.

This is how name lookup works within class member function definitions. In this case, since there are no scope resolution operators(::) before the variable names, an unqualified lookup is performed. The rule for it states (emphasis mine):

For a name used inside a member function body, a default argument of a member function, exception specification of a member function, or a default member initializer, the scopes searched are the same as in class definition, except that the entire scope of the class is considered, not just the part prior to the declaration that uses the name.

That's why, from the language standard perspective, the identifier name in your getInfo() can be used to refer to teacher::name declared later in your source code, as it is declared within "the entire scope of the class". The key point here is that the name lookup for member function body uses a different rule from that for class definitions or free functions. You may find the details of the lookup rules of those in the link above.
One of the reasons that declarations are required before use in most occasions is that the compiler has to know what a specific identifier is (for example, whether teacher is the name of a variable or a type) before it can be processed correctly. However, in the case of class member function definitions, the compiler can postpone the handling of the function definition after the class definition, hence the name lookup rule can be relaxed. It also makes it possible to write the public interface and special member functions(e.g. constructors) before the class implementation details in a class definition, which is a order preferred by many because it puts the info that is the most important for the user of a class at the front.
Note that there is a separate rule for qualified name lookups that makes using teacher::name instead of just name in your getInfo() function also valid (but unnecessary).

i think in C++ classes member variables are visible throughout the entire class regardless of their declaration order, unlike local variables in functions which must be declared before use.
